# Java regex: How to determine if a string contains words not in the list

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a requirement where I need to check if an input string contains only those words I treat as valid and every other word as invalid.

For example: Assume valid words as 'apple','orange' and 'potato'. When an input string "There is apple and orange" is given, I need to flag an error because I expect the string to contain 'apple' or 'orange' or both but not words like "There" "is" and "and". How can I do this using Java Regex? or what other options I have?

Comment: Split your sentence into words and then compare each words against your list

Comment: It's been marked as "too broad" and put on hold but the answers provided are quite specific to my question.

Comment: With regex you can try by use of a negative [look](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)ahead: [`"\\b(?!(?:apple|orange|potato)\\b)\\w+\\b"`](http://fiddle.re/1atx16) (click "Java")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your input so you have individual words, then check if each one is valid:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  List<String> allowed = Arrays.asList("apple", "orange", "potato");
  String input = "There is apple and orange";
  System.out.println(isValid(input, allowed));
}

boolean isValid(String input, List<String> allowed){
  String[] words = input.split("\\s+");
  for(String word:words){
    if(!allowed.contains(word)){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Split into words, copy into a set (or list), then use `Collection.removeAll` to remove the allowed words, leaving only the "invalid" ones:

```
Set<String> invalidWords = new HashSet<>(input.split("\\s+"));
invalidWords.removeAll(allowedWords);
System.out.println(invalidWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

- put the valid words in a set
- split the string into individual words
- verify that the set contains all the words